# Syntax error when trying to check the time stamp of a .csv file

Tags: python, syntax, path

I have a csv file that I want to print out to screen, and then re-read the file every time it changes. I have the python working to format & print out the file, but I am stuck on checking the time stamp so it will re-read & print after a change. It just gives me a syntax error that I have not been able to fathom. I know the path is correct as it is used to open the csv file.

This is the error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\last50.py", line 7
    def __init__(self):        self._cached_stamp = 0  self.filename = 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Wsjt-x\wsjtx.log'
                               ^
Syntax error: invalid syntax
```

Here is the complete script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import sys
import os
class Monkey(object):
    def __init__(self):        self._cached_stamp = 0  self.filename = 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Wsjt-x\wsjtx.log'
    def ook(self):        stamp = os.stat(self.filename).st_mtime
    if stamp != self._cached_stamp:            self._cached_stamp = stamp

# File has changed, so do something...

with open('C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Wsjt-x\wsjtx.log') as csvfile:

    fieldnames = ('date1', 'time1', 'date2','time2','callsign',)
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    count = 0
    headers = dict( (n,n) for n in fieldnames )

    for row in reader:
        count += 1
        print'{:<9} {:12} {:12}'.format(row['callsign'],row['date1'],row['time1'])

print "Found " + str(count) + " rows"
```

Comment: If that's really how your code is formatted, then the syntax error is because it is not indented properly. Proper indentation is ***extremely*** important in Python as it defines how and when the lines of code are executed. I suggest you study some language tutorials and lean how to do this fundamental thing for yourself.

Comment: Note I also **strongly suggest** you upgrade to Python 3 ASAP because Python 2 support ended over two years ago and it is [no longer supported](https://devguide.python.org/devcycle/#end-of-life-branches).

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed indentation Martineau- fixed now, thanks.